# What is the standard unit of time for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, pagespeed

Hey I am trying to figure out what units of time this is measured in anyone know? I would think it would be standard for all JavaScript so I think this is all the information you would need.

Huge Thanks In Advance!

```
$('.slider-text-image').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshowSpeed: 4000,
        animationDuration: 600,
        controlNav: true,
        keyboardNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        pauseOnAction: true  

});
```

Comment: Generally milliseconds, but have you tried timing it?

Comment: Ya just figured it out if you post a answer I will mark u as best answer

Comment: I do believe it's milliseconds, and I do believe it's stated several times in the documentation for flexSlider, as well as being the unit of time used in practically all javascript, from timeOuts to jQuery animations ?

Comment: re-open.  Made the question more general

Comment: You can't _know_ just from the snippet. A javascript library doesn't necessarily expect milliseconds... it could expect seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years, decades, centuries, millenia, etc. You'd have to look at either the documentation or the implementation to be absolutely certain. That said, you'd be pretty safe betting on milliseconds; it's the general convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, milliseconds.

```
4000 // 4 seconds
600  // 0.6 seconds
```

Though in my own programs/animations I tend to store them as seconds, because I find it easier to work with. Only converting to milliseconds when I need to because that is what some function expects with `(time * 1000)`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [here](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)*:

- **slideshowSpeed**

  --  Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, *in milliseconds*
- **animationSpeed**

  -- Integer: Set the speed of animations, *in milliseconds*

*This answer came from the very first result from a simple google search for [jquery flexslider](https://www.google.com/?q=jquery%20flexslider#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+flexslider&oq=jquery+flexslider&fp=546ed266f63f375). Please put a little research effort into future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out its milliseconds so "4000" is 4 seconds since there is 1000 milliseconds in  second.